# Failed to convert @color/Blue into a drawable when setting background color

Tags: android

res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@color/Blue">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

meanwhile, res/values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="Blue">#0000FF</color>
</resources>
```

as you can see, the color does start with #

The code is exactly as you see it.

Comment: how it start with <color name="Blue">#0000FFF</color>

Comment: Is your Blue supposed to have only six chars? So #0000FF not #0000FFF

Comment: use this site to specify your color http://www.colorhexa.com/0000ff

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have to go to File-->Invalidate Cache/Restart.

It amazes me that this bug still hasn't been fixed in Android Studio, searching on SO it looks like it has plagued other people in different ways.

Comment: Error continues to happen for me even after Invalidate and Restart. Android Studio 1.2.2 on OS X.

Comment: @Aaron Same thing for me, find a solution?

Comment: I never found one, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing instead of adding colour through colour.xml then to activity_main.xml just directly add the value of colour to activity_main.xml by its hash colour code directly 
For example in your case`android:background="#0000FF"`