# Failed to convert colour into a drawable

Tags: android, xml, colors, background, render

So I am very new to android programming and I have an issue which I can't figure out at all.

i want to make the background of my text the colour red which i was learning in a basic tutorial. 
however, the problem is when i change the background colour, i get an error:

> "Rendering Problems Failed to convert red into a drawable"

this is my code that i have written in the activity_main:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:background="red"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my colours.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
<color name="Red">#E60000</color>
</resources>`
```

i have even tried to change line 10 to `android:background="@color/red`
    or  `android:background="color/red` and even  `android:background="@android:color/red` but nothing seems to have worked.

Would someone be able to help me fix this issue?

Comment: Try this `android:background="#f00`

Comment: maybe you habe same issue as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618785/failed-to-convert-color-blue-into-a-drawable-when-setting-background-color

Comment: `color name="Red"` try `color name="red"`, instead. Resource names are case sensitive. And have to be all lower case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do it...

1.-Create a `Value Resource File` named `color.xml` then add this inside of it

```
<color name="red">#ffff0000</color>
```

2.-Now change your `TextView` to this and should work.

```
<TextView
android:text="@string/hello_world"
android:background="@color/red"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

If you want get that color via code you have to use

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.red)
```

Or also you can declare your color like [@DerGolem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2649012/der-golem) said using

```
<TextView
android:text="@string/hello_world"
android:background="#FF0000"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: this worked like a charm, thank you very much! very well explained!

Comment: @carlsaptarshi why did you remove this question as acceptable?

Comment: i did? i didnt know i had!!?? completely by accident, my bad

Answer (score 2):

`@color/red` only works when you have defined a red color resource in your colors.xml file (located under res/values)

If you don't want to have to input the color value into your colors.xml file, try instead to change the value of `android:background` to a hex value for red, such as #ff0000.

Answer (score 2):

Add a file colors.xml (in res/values) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:background="@color/Red"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Since you are using some ressources files to declare colors, you need to add the "@color/" to allow the OS to know you're making reference to a ressource file.

Then in your color.xml, you named your color like "Red" but in the activity file you're calling the id "red", Be aware that Id are case sensitive. So you were on the right track, your only mistake was to have a "R" in the ressource file and a "r" in the background color changing ;)

Hope it helps

EDIT:

You could also directly use android's OS Color, they can be reach the same way as Id, just replace the Id part with Color, [See Doc here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#RED).